# how to get max and min from a raster using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator, statistics

I have a land surface temperature raster file and I want the max and min of it.

```
minLSTresult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster_result, "MINIMUM")

minLST = minLSTresult.getOutput(0)
```

`minLST` returns `u'261.22'`. How could I only get the number of it?

Comment: minLSTresult should return your value. Try print minLSTresult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is simply indicating that the value is a [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) string. You can use this unicode string in most situations. However, if you need to fully control the type, convert it to [float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) format.

```
test = unicode('261.22')

>>> test
u'261.22'

>>> type(test)
<type 'unicode'>

test2 = float(test)
>>> test2
261.22

>>> type(test2)
<type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 13):

Create a [raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) object using the full path to your raster. Raster objects have the properties `minimum` and `maximum`.

```
>>> rastFullPath = r"C:\Rasters\rasters.gdb\Slope"
>>> rast = arcpy.Raster (rastFullPath)
>>> rast.minimum
0.0
>>> rast.maximum
64.9616928100586
```

Or you can use your method and convert the output from `unicode` to `float`:

```
>>> float (arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (rast, "MAXIMUM").getOutput (0))
64.9616928100586
>>> float (arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (rast, "MINIMUM").getOutput (0))
0.0
```